# Replace an asterisk (*) using Perl regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following string:

`$_='364*84252';`

The question is: how to replace `*` in the string with something else? I've tried `s/\*/$i/`, but there is an error:  `Quantifier follows nothing in regex`. On the other hand `s/'*'/$i/` doesn't cause any errors, but it also doesn't seem to have any effect at all.

Comment: The second example is searching for one or more apostophes, that's why it isn't working. The first should work though, as noted by the answers given.

Comment: @Brad: As currently concocted, the `$i` is in the RHS; `/o` only address the match portion on the LHS of a `s///` operation.

Answer (score 8):

Something else is weird here...

```
~> cat test.pl
$a = "234*343";
$i = "FOO";

$a =~ s/\*/$i/;
print $a;

~> perl test.pl
234FOO343
```

Found something:

```
~> cat test.pl
$a = "234*343";
$i = "*4";

$a =~ m/$i/;
print $a;

~> perl test.pl
Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/* <-- HERE 4/ at test.pl line 4.
```

Solution, escape the special characters from the variable using `\Q` and `\E`, for example (TIMTOWTDI)

```
~> cat test.pl
$a = "234*343";
$i = "*4";

$a =~ m/\Q$i\E/;
print $a;

~> perl test.pl
234*343
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perl -le '$_="364*84252";s/\*/xx/;print'
364xx84252
```

Definitely works.  Perhaps you're using double-quotes in a oneline instead of single quotes?  I'm not sure - I can't reproduce your results at all.  You'll need to give a bit more background to your problem, preferably with code we can run to reproduce your results.

Answer (score 2):

*It must be a psh issue then. Running script with perl xx.pl does not throw any errors. Thanks for help ;)*

Strings do their own escaping of backslashes. In this case you should probably double the backslashes to `s/\\*/$i/`

Comment: I’m not sure if you meant a quadruple backslash there. I just formatted in in `Courier`, but didn’t change your code. You might look it over again if you’ve a chance.

Comment: @tchrist: The quadruple was because markdown requires one to quote backslashes outside code sections. You should have halved them  before putting them it in such a section ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Better yet use

```
$InputLine =~ s/\Q*\E//g;
```

This should remove the asterisks anywhere in the variable string.

Answer (score 0):

The error must be coming from `$i`.  `s/\*/foo/` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$VARIABLE =~ s/\Q*\E//;
```

Comment: in this case you won’t need the `\E`, because nothing follows it.

Comment: I would be great to explain your answer a bit instead of writing a single line. This looks more like a comment to me ...